# Lookup column value not updated - ListsWebServices and Asp.NET

Tags: sharepoint-server, web-services, caml-query, asp.net

I am having trouble inserting *new record* in **"Clients"** list on our server, I am in learning phase for working with **SharePoint Lists** **Web Services** and I am trying to insert a new item in a list which contains ID of another list item.

Following is my code for setting lookup column value before sending data to `webservice`.

```
batch.InnerXml = "<Method ID='1' Cmd='New'>"
                + "<Field Name='" + Constants.Client_Field_FirstName + "'>" + clientObj.FirstNameOfIndividual + "</Field>"
                + "<Field Name='" + Constants.Client_Field_MiddleInitial + "'>" + clientObj.MiddleNameOfIndividual + "</Field>"                    
                //Save parent  id's
                + "<Field Name='" + Constants.CLIENT_FIELD_PARENT_ID + "'>" +  string.Format("{0};#", clientObj.ParentCaregiver1ID) + "</Field>"
                + "<Field Name='" + Constants.CLIENT_FIELD_PARENT_ID + "'>" + string.Format("{0};#", clientObj.ParentCaregiver2ID) + "</Field>"
                + "</Method>";
```

Basically I want `Parent 1` and `Parent 2 ID's` to be inserted for new client. I don't know what is missing here. Client is added to the list and there is no error message but Parent ID's are blank.

Am I using right format for inserting lookup column value?

Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `Constants.CLIENT_FIELD_PARENT_ID` is the name of a multivalue lookup column then the value for that should be in the format `Id1;#Value1;#Id2;#Value2` or without values `Id1;#;#Id2;#`

Which will give this code

```
batch.InnerXml = "<Method ID='1' Cmd='New'>"
                + "<Field Name='" + Constants.Client_Field_FirstName + "'>" + clientObj.FirstNameOfIndividual + "</Field>"
                + "<Field Name='" + Constants.Client_Field_MiddleInitial + "'>" + clientObj.MiddleNameOfIndividual + "</Field>"                    
                //Save parent  id's
                + "<Field Name='" + Constants.CLIENT_FIELD_PARENT_ID + "'>" +  string.Format("{0};#;#{1};#", clientObj.ParentCaregiver1ID, clientObj.ParentCaregiver2ID) + "</Field>"
                + "</Method>";
```

See [Updating Multi Value Fields Using Web Service Call And Batch Update](https://pholpar.wordpress.com/2010/01/26/updating-multi-value-fields-using-web-service-call-and-batch-update/)